# "netstat" data for Multicast, Unicast and Broadcast

Tags: linux

I am looking to get netstat for BroadCast, Multicast and Unicast sent and received packets. This can be obtained from "/proc/net/netstat". But the problem here is, it does not give statistics data for different interfaces(like "eth0", "eth2" etc..). It only gives total data for all the interfaces.

How to get this data for each interfaces?

Comment: You should accept one answer, if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a subset(including multicast) of the information per device from:

```
/proc/net/dev
```

Comment: /proc/net/dev does not have unicast and broadcast data. Looks like ethtool has it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rx and tx broadcast and multicast for each interface from 
`#ethtool -S ethX` . The same multicast data is there in `/proc/net/dev` file.